# How to Override Client Side Soap Logging - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, logging, soap, spring-boot

I'm consuming a soap webservice inside a spring boot application. The response/request logging is too big, because of one attribute which is too large. So I want to intercept that logging and remove the offending attribute.

I've been messing about with SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor, but i think that is just for Server side logging. It will not get picked up.

I have configured my soap logging inside yml as follows:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    ...
  level:
    ...
    org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent: TRACE
    org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received: TRACE
    org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing: DEBUG
```

That works fine for logging both request and response, but I need to remove a very large problematic attribute from the envelope. Any ideas?

Comment: Am I understood correctly, you want to cut some text from log message depending on the message content? Or you want to show logs only in case if log message does not contain some specific content

Comment: Inside the soap Envelope, I want to replace a particular attribute (for example)  <attributeA>asdasd...</attributeA>  with <attributeA>removed too large</attributeA> ., In all cases, that attribute. I have the logic for doing that with regex. I just don't know how to hook it in.

Comment: Well in this case I think the only option you have is to create your own SOAPLoggingInterceptor e manage request and soap according to yuor own specifications

Comment: There is no hook near where the request and response are logged in trace level. You can create implementation for  `ClientInterceptor`s `handleRequest` and `handleResponse`  to  parse,  modify and log your custom message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `ClientInterceptorAdapter` the abstract implementation `ClientInterceptor`s and oveeride `handleRequest` and `handleResponse` to parse, modify and log your custom message.

The below code delegates to `AbstractLoggingInterceptor` `handleRequest` and `handleResponse` and overrides the `logMessage` to create a custom message.

Something like

```
public class MyInterceptor extend ClientInterceptorAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyInterceptor.class);

    private EndpointInterceptor endpointInterceptor = new AbstractLoggingInterceptor() {
        @Override
        protected Source getSource(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) {
            // Base logic same as SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor getSource method.You can adjust to your preference.
            if(webServiceMessage instanceof SoapMessage) {
                SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage)webServiceMessage;
                return soapMessage.getEnvelope().getSource();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void logMessage(String message) {
            // You can use your regex to remove the attribute and log the message.
            this.logger.debug(message);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return endpointInterceptor.handleRequest(messageContext, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return endpointInterceptor.handleResponse(messageContext, null);

    }

}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer as it seems to suit my needs better than the @Oleksandr Shpota's answer (and I'm out of bounty time). I haven't had a chance to test it properly so I will provide further feedback later in the week. Thanks.

Comment: That was the best 50 pts I ever spent. Thanks! Note to future interested parties: You may find it necessary to override isLogEnabled() in the EndPointInterceptor as it is only true for debug level by default. Also remove spring's MessageTracing properties/yml otherwise you will get double logging.

Comment: Also, to omit the empty methods, instead of implementing ClientInterceptor, MyInterceptor can extend ClientInterceptorAdapter

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way of doing that. You ether implement your own `Logger` by [extending sl4j API](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#slf4j_compatible) or wrap log calls and do the transformations there.

The first way will require some efforts because you'll need to implement batch of classes and make sure that the other parts of log system are not broken.

But second part is pretty strait forward.
You have ti create a logger wrapper which implements `Logger` interface, could be something like this:

```
public class LoggerWrapper extends MarkerIgnoringBase {
    private final Logger logger;

    public LoggerWrapper(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private String transformMessage(String input) {
        // do all needed regexp transformations here
    }

    @Override
    public void debug(String msg) {
        String transformedMessage = transformMessage(msg);
        // delegate log call to inner logger
        logger.debug(transformedMessage);
    }

    // implement the rest of the methods here
}
```

And in the code you might use it like this:

```
private static final Logger log = new LoggerWrapper(
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class)
);
```

You can also wrap the logger without implementing `Logger` interface (in my case it is `MarkerIgnoringBase` class). In that case you'll not need to implement number of methods from the interface, however you'll louse interchangeability.

The drawback of this solution is that you have to log the messages in advance on your side (not via `MessageTracing`) but if it is possible I would go this way. On the other hand the first solution does it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to go with the second answer as it suits my purposes better.